# Required item type of value of variable $duration is xs:string supplied value has item type xs:dayTimeDuration

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have got two different timestamps in milliseconds. For these two timestamps I want to know a duration between them. The duration is correct calculated, but I want format this duration and then the Eclipse give me this error:

> Required item type of value of variable $duration is xs:string
>   supplied value has item type xs:dayTimeDuration

```
<xsl:variable name="start" select='xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + 1512037112064 * xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001S")'/>
<xsl:variable name="end" select='xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00") + 1512059856670 * xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001S")'/>

<xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime($end)-xs:dateTime($start)" />
```

Output without any formation

> PT6H19M4.606S

Wanted formatted output

> 6:19:4.606

Comment: Does `translate(string(xs:dateTime($end)-xs:dateTime($start)), 'HMPTS', '::')` suffice?

Comment: You can use [this trick: "How to correctly use XSD Duration?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14926467/1305969).

Comment: Both solution worked for me.

Comment: Your question does not have a variable called $duration. Moreover there seem to be two separate issues (a) output not in the desired format, (b) a type error. I'm left confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you have two timestamps `$endTS` and `$startTS` in milliseconds the easiest way to get the duration between them is

```
xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0.001S') * ($endTS - $startTS)
```

You don't need to add both to a dummy start time and then subtract two dummy dateTime values.

Secondly, if you want to format a duration in H:M:S format, then if you know the duration is less than 24 hours, you can use

```
format-time(xs:time('00:00:00') + $duration, '[H1]:[m1]:[s1].[f000]')
```

If you don't know it's less than 24 hours you can use

```
concat(days-from-duration($d)*24 + hours-from-duration($d), ':',
  minutes-from-duration($d), ':', seconds-from-duration($d))
```

I don't know what caused the type error; the code you have shown does not declare or use a variable called `$duration`.

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake. I changed the code little bit and then a I did not check it. The variable duration is just variable, where I try translate the `PT6H19M4.606S` to this-wanted output `6:19:4.606`.